# Is there a way to convert à,è,é,ë, ... to html &aacute; &eacute; &egrave; &auml;

Tags: twig

is there a twig way to convert `à,è,é,ë, ...`  to html `&aacute; &eacute; &egrave; &auml; ...` ? (not the other way around!)

EDIT

Thanks to [docu](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service), the following almost solves my desiderata. I just need to define `Myapp\Twig\MyappExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace Myapp\Twig;

class MyappExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('htmlentities', array($this, 'htmlentitiesFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function htmlentitiesFilter($string)
    {
         $hstring =  htmlentities($string);
         return $hstring;
    }
}
?>
```

and within `service.yml`

```
services:
    myapp.twig.myapp_extension:
        class: Myapp\Twig\MyappExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

I get what I wish by `{{ string|htmlentities|raw}}`.

Minor annoyance, I do not see how to get rid of that  `raw` (without which I get `&amp;agrave;` instead of `&agrave;`).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom filter

```
$filter = new Twig_Filter('htmlentities', function ($string) {
    return htmlentities($string);
});
```

Then add it:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Finally, use it as:

```
{{ 'Twig'|htmlentities }}
```

Comment: well... to your `$twig` object. If you're using a framework, you're gonna have to look into it.

Comment: Ok, of course. I am using Symfony 3, I'll check where it is hidden, and how I may hack it. I'll be back.

Comment: Hi, I am looking at [https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html), is it?